# Using Sessions for keeping score has a vulnerability on page reload that can be used to exploit score

Tags: php

First here is a quick preview of how my program works. I have a PHP quiz in which if a user gets an answer right it is set to display certain things including the addition of points to the users score and it also reloads the page and displays the next question. If the user guesses wrong the same thing happens but it subtracts score instead. All of this works fine however, I did find one major vulnerability which is that if the user reloads the page it will return to the first question but it will keep the current score. So if you are on question 4 with 40 score and you need to reload the page it does set you back to the first question as it should but it keeps that 40 score.

Now I cannot do something where on page reload it resets the score because my quiz after a question is answered right or wrong reloads the page to display the next question. This would then mean that the session would end after every question which is not what I want and the whole purpose of me using session is to keep the scoring when it reloads to the next question. Now my first thought was to create an if statement that checked whether or not the question was back to 1 (which happens after a page reload) it would reset the score to 0. I tried this however it does not reset the score back to 0 rather it still stays counting up. Here is the code I tried:

```
if($currentQuestion==1){
         $_SESSION['score'] == 0;
     }
```

Now here is the code in the entirety of my PHP. I feel like including little snippets of sections may not give a full look at the depth of my program and what I am trying to solve so I am just going to post it in its entirety (I will be excluding the arrays though as they are not needed to show it):

```
<?php
session_start();

$questionsAndAnwsers = array(array("question" => " What early cartoon   character created by the Disney Studio was Mickey Mouse based off of ?",       "answer" => "Oswald The Lucky Rabbit"),

//rest of arrays were here ignore this comment 

$_SESSION["count"];
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}

// current question
$currentQuestion = 0;

if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
     $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
     if(isset($questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion])){

     $currentAnswer = $questionsAndAnwsers["$currentQuestion"] ["answer"];

     if($currentQuestion==15){
     session_destroy();
        header("Location: http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/loginmain.html"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
     }
     else if($_POST["guess"] == $currentAnswer){
          $currentQuestion++;
         $guess = $_POST['guess'];
         print ("<span class='Stylize2'>Your answer: $guess <br>"); 
         print("The answer expected: $currentAnswer<br>");  
         print("Answer Correct $answerCorrect<br><br>");
         $images = [
          1 => 'MickeyMouse.png',
          2 => 'Philo.jpg',
          3 => 'warner.jpg',
          4 => 'superman.jpg',
          5 => 'own.jpg',
          6 => 'scooby.png',
          7 => 'garfield.jpg',
          8 => 'pok1.jpg',
          9 => 'peanuts.jpg',
          10 => 'sam.jpg',
          11 => 'haim.jpg',
          12 => 'back.jpg',
          13 => 'joe.jpg',
          14 => 'r.png',
          15 => 'wild.jpg',

  ];

  if( array_key_exists($currentQuestion, $images))
      echo "<img src='{$images[$currentQuestion]}'   alt='$images[$currentQuestion]' height='200'><br><br>";
 else
     echo "Not found";
     $_SESSION['score']+=10;
     echo $_SESSION['score'];
     print("&nbsp;points");
     echo "<br>";
         print("Next Question Below<br></span><br><br>");
       } 

       else {
         $currentQuestion=0;
         $guess = $_POST['guess'];
         print ("<span class='Stylize'>Your answer: $guess <br>");   
         print("You have failed..<br>"); 
         echo '<img src=angry.gif height="200"><br><br>';
         $_SESSION['score']-=5;
         echo $_SESSION['score'];
         print("&nbsp;points");
         echo "<br><br>";
         echo "</span>";
     $test = '251993__kwahmah-02__distorted-voice-18.wav';
     echo '<audio autoplay loop>';
     echo "<source src='$test' type='audio/wav'>";
     echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element';
     echo '</audio>';
       }
       }else{
          exit("Question not found!");
       }
       if($currentQuestion==1){
         $_SESSION['score'] == 0;
     }
    }
?>
```

I did leave the if statement that is not working in to show you all where it is placed. I also understand this is a lot of code and if anyone has any edit suggestions to trim it down well then do suggest but for now since I don't know what I should exclude I am showcasing it all.

Comment: You already keep Q&A in an array. I would keep the results from each answer in an array as well, and then calculate the score always as a sum of such array. This way - I think - the whole accounting business should be more manageable. You should probably keep the "currentQuestion" also as part of the session.

Comment: @sal those are some very good ideas especially to keep the currentQuestion as part of the session to. However, I did also realize a flaw in my design well not a flaw but simply how it is designed that will cause an issue anyways. Currently if a user gets a question wrong they must start over and if I make the session score go back to zero it will ruin the quiz and scoring system in general.

Comment: @sal is right you should keep the `currentQuestion` in the session and don't let the user manipulate it. Otherwhise he can move back forward/behind the questions, to get more points for example. It is better to save maximum of vulnerable stuff server side

Comment: Keep track fo both score and selected answer, if a question has an answer selected when the page for it is loaded (ie, reload and back to Q1) then re-select the previously chosen value for the user.  Present user with score AFTER quiz is submitted and no more changes are allowed.